# Uneditable fields in attribute table

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, fields-attributes

I have data in a .csv sheet that I imported as a vector layer into QGIS. I then joined the imported table with an existing .shp file. The fields that I joined into the .shp file are not editable (they remain greyed) and I notice the field value is 0. Is the uneditable field related to the field value?

In addition, when I updated my .csv sheet, the linked layer within QGIS gets updated automatically but the attributes in the .shp file don't get updated. Why is this so?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't edit CSV's in QGIS. If the result of the Join is blank values, I'm guessing the data types in the columns wasn't read correctly, and you need to add the CSV to QGIS via the 'add delimited text layer' option.

Comment: I added the csv using the 'add delimited text layer' option and used a .csvt file to define the attribute types (mainly strings and integers) of the .csv file. The result of the join is not blank, it contains uneditable text which i would like to edit. How do i make the text editable?
Thanks!

Comment: Save the joined layer to a new geopackage or shapefile. The new layer will have all columns editable.